# retrieve unseen/hidden objects from a listview using setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I have the object Human, which has the following fields :

1. Name
2. Surname
3. DOB (date of birth)

I have a custom adapter that is being utilized to show a set of items in a list view, which is being fed an arraylist of type Human.

```
    ArrayList<Human> al = new ArrayList<Human>();
    al = fillMyArraylist(); //abstracted method that does what it says

    myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter (this, al);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My myAdapter class (which extends BaseAdapter) has a a custom XML that only shows the name and surname, but not the DOB.

Then I am using the method setOnItemClickListener

```
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            TextView nameTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.NametextView);
            TextView surnameTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SurnametextView);
            String name= nameTV.getText().toString();
            String surname= surnameTV .getText().toString();

        }
    });
```

However, since the AL (of type Human) has also the DOB included in it, is there anyway I can retrieve it using setOnItemClickListener ?

What I tried to do till now, is to create a new row inside my custom XML and hide it, and use it to retrieve the data, but I assume it is a workaround and not an ideal solution. Any hints ?

Comment: something like Human a1 = al.get(position); maybe

Comment: Looks a nice approach, no idea how I missed that. will apply now. fingers crossed.